# Compare additional fields only if multiple matches?

Tags: mongodb

I have unique documents which are indexed by non-unique keys. What makes this document unique, is the combination of multiple keys within the document. For example:

```
{
  first: 'John',
  last: 'Foo'
}
{
  first: 'Henry',
  last: 'Bar'
}
{
  first: 'Frank',
  last: 'Foo'
}
{
  first: 'John',
  last: 'Bar'
}
```

So, based on the example above: If we wanted to query for the first name of `Frank`, we would only get one result. Ideally, since we only have one result, we wouldn't even need to compare the last name to our query. However, if we query for the name `John`, we would get two results, so we *would* need to compare the secondary argument.

How would this style of query be achieved in Mongo? The goal is simply to save needless compares if there is only a single match to begin with.

Note that i am aware that this style of query doesn't guarantee the correct document. It assumes that the primary, and each subsequent field match, is "good enough" to verify the identity of the document, *if only one document is matched*. Though if there are other less obvious reasons why this method should not be used, by all means discuss it :)

Comment: any reason adding `limit(1)` and `sort()` parameters don't work?

Comment: `limit(1)` wouldn't match the 2nd/etc argument if multiple matches were found, so you would not be able to filter through incorrect matches. As far as `sort()`, i don't think so.. though perhaps there is some usage of sort that i am not familiar with

Comment: So you're trying to prevent MongoDB from having to check for `last = 'Foo'` in the `Frank` case, purely for performance reasons?

Comment: Yes. Obviously this example is quite simple, but i imagine there are cases where the performance of additional length, especially complex, comparisons would be better off saved and not used. Thoughts?

Comment: My thoughts are that this isn't a very interesting or useful use case. :)

Comment: Quite possibly, i am very unfamiliar with MongoDB at the moment, so this "problem" that i (only mildly) encountered may simply be a case of over/premature optimization. Something that would be better solved with different data design, rather than how you query it. Nevertheless it is above my knowledge line with Mongo, so i figured i would ask it here. You may be completely right :)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't worry about this at all, especially if you have an index on this. A compound index on first, last will only scan the index elements that start with "first". If that's one document, then it stops. If you it also needs to match "last", then it will scan those parts of the index.

Comment: > If you it also needs to match "last", then it will scan those parts of the index. < It sounds as if you are describing the question i raised, along with a different type of "full compare" query. Could you provide an example of the two? Or perhaps give me the names/search for the types of queries you are referencing? :)

Comment: A "full compare" query is not something to worry about at all in an index... I'll try to come up with a good example over the weekend